# How can I get a graphic result in c# and visual studio environment?

Tags: c#, graphic

I wanna show a result of current vs time data as a graphical representation of it.It consist of a two dimentional matrix data. I am talking about a classic line graph that shows the change of current with respect to time.

Comment: Where are you stuck at? Can you create a window? Are you looking for the names of the components that you can use to plot your data?

Comment: I couldn't understand what you want to visualize.

Comment: Depending on what you're looking for, doing a web search for `c# line graph` yields some promising results including code examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey everyone ZedGraph happens to be the best solution for me. I've tried it.

- You can plot dynamic data
- It is very easy -to- use c# Library
- It automaticly adds a graph tool to toolbox.

So there you go. I hope everyone who needs this can get the result.

Answer (score 1):

I think I am looking for ways to do a similar thing: I want to have graphs that can be dynamically updated while using C#. I found OxyPlot promising. See http://oxyplot.codeplex.com/.

[This is a very good explanation on creating graphs in WPF using OxyPlot](http://blog.bartdemeyer.be/2013/03/creating-graphs-in-wpf-using-oxyplot/) which I am sure you can use for your own needs.

If you happen to find a better solution let me know ;-).

Comment: ZedGraph is also very good. You should try. Easy and efficient.